# Session Hijacking in drupal 7.53

Tags: security, drupal-7

I can use session details of other users and can do the session hijacking.

For ex.
I am login with a user 'A' and saves the session cookie of 'A' and logout. Now I login with another user 'B' and after login replace the session cookie with the session cookie of 'A' with the help of Burp tool or any browser extension tool.

Now I can perform action like 'A'. As 'A' is login now without any login details. This is very highly critical issue.

Also I can upload double extension file (for ex. filename.exe.txt).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

But you're forgetting the most important part of session hijacking, which is, How do you get access to others session cookies? You can replace your cookies to login on any site, after all, that's how they work, they're used to simulate a state in a stateless protocol like HTTP, that's the expected behaviour.

The real problem here is how you can get the session cookie of other users to impersonate them. For example, if the session cookies are generated by using a predictable algorithm, i.e. using an auto-incrementing session token that will always add 1 to the previous one, with this you can just get you session cookie, subtract 1 and voilá, you'll be authenticated as a different user.

Another way to get session cookies is with XSS attacks, if the cookies are not flagged as HTTP only, then you can get them via javascript and send them to your server, where you'll use them to impersonate different users.

However, just grabbing your session cookie and using it in a different browser and getting logged in as that user without credentials, it's not a session hijacking at all, that's just the intended behaviour.

What I see as a problem here, is that you said that you logged out as A and it didn't expired your session token, since you could still use user's A cookie, but besides that, I don't see any problem.

Comment: Thanks Esteban for reply. I agree with you.

Comment: Don't worry, we're here to help ;)

Comment: Sorry for delay response. But Thanks for suggestion. It's clear now.